# Sum Like Values in List

Tags: c#

I have a list that contains a list of objects:

```
public QuestionScores {
    public string QuestionReference { get; set; }
    public int StudentScore { get; set: }
    public int QuestionScore { get; set; }
}
```

the list contains objects with the same Question Reference:

```
{ "U1C1", 1, 4 }
{ "U1C1", 3, 4 }
{ "U1C2", 2, 4 }
```

I want to end up with a list like this:

```
{ "U1C1", 4, 8 }
{ "U1C2", 2, 4 }
```

I want to sum the StudentScore and QuestionScore into a single QuestionReference.
Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried doing yourself and how has it not worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group by your `QuestionReference`:

```
var result = myList.GroupBy(x => x.QuestionReference)
    .Select(x => new QuestionScores { 
        QuestionReference = x.Key, 
        StudentScore = x.Sum(y => y.StudentScore),
        QuestionScore = x.Sum(y => y.QuestionScore)
    }
);
```

See also [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-8.0)